# Difference of two time stamp in proper format

Tags: python, shell, unix

I have 2 time stamps in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.

```
d1=20180110141907
d2=20180110141907
```

I want a shell script which find out the difference between 2 above dates and give the output as "4days 22hrs 56min 04sec".

Comment: This seems simple to do, do you have an actual question and things you tried and didn't work, or do you know how to do it but just hope somebody else will do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your time stam is unix time

```
#! /bin/bash

FIRST_DATE="20180110141907"
SECOND_DATE="20080100141907" 

TIME_DIFF=$(expr ${FIRST_DATE} - ${SECOND_DATE} )

SECONDS_ON_DAY="86400"
SECONDS_ON_HOUR="3600"
SECONDS_ON_MINUTE="60"


DAYS=$(expr ${TIME_DIFF} / ${SECONDS_ON_DAY})
HOURS=$(expr ${TIME_DIFF} % ${SECONDS_ON_DAY} / ${SECONDS_ON_HOUR})
MINUTES=$(expr ${TIME_DIFF} % ${SECONDS_ON_HOUR} / ${SECONDS_ON_MINUTE})
SECONDS=$(expr ${TIME_DIFF} % ${SECONDS_ON_MINUTE})

echo ${TIME_DIFF}
echo  "${DAYS}days ${HOURS}hrs ${MINUTES}min ${SECONDS}sec"
```

Comment: The stamps are probably not seconds since the epoch, they look more like YYYYMMDDHHMMSS to me.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, appreciate your work. But I am not getting the desire output. And yes the format of the input is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Answer (score 0):

This is not difficult, but it does require several steps: parse the incoming time format, find the difference in seconds, and the calculate the different time units of the difference.

Given

```
d1=20180110141907
d2=20180111162211
```

GNU awk

```
gawk -v start="$d1" -v stop="$d2" '
    function str2time(time,    re, arr, t) {
        re = "([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})"
        t = -1
        if (match(time, re, arr))
            t = mktime(arr[1] " " arr[2] " " arr[3] " " arr[4] " " arr[5] " " arr[6])
        return t
    }
    BEGIN {
        t1 = str2time(start)
        t2 = str2time(stop)
        diff = t2 - t1
        if (diff < 0) diff = -diff       #awk does not have abs()
        days  = int(diff / 86400); diff %= 86400
        hours = int(diff / 3600);  diff %= 3600
        mins  = int(diff / 60);    diff %= 60
        printf("%d days %d hours %d mins %d secs\n", days, hours, mins, diff)
    }
'
```

```
1 days 2 hours 3 mins 4 secs
```

Perl

```
perl -MTime::Piece -sE '
    $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime($start, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
    $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime($stop,  "%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
    $diff = abs($t2 - $t1);
    $days  = int($diff / 86400); $diff %= 86400;
    $hours = int($diff / 3600);  $diff %= 3600;
    $mins  = int($diff / 60);    $diff %= 60;
    printf "%d days %d hours %d mins %d secs\n", $days, $hours, $mins, $diff;
' -- -start="$d1" -stop="$d2"
```

```
1 days 2 hours 3 mins 4 secs
```